# Scale a particular feature in a NumPy array which have more than one features using minmaxScalar from sklearn

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a numpy array with 4 features. I want to scale the second feature using sklearn's minMaxScalar. 
Let the features be A,B,C,D.
The numpy array is
   [     [1,2,3,4],       [5,6,7,8],    [9,10,11,12],    [13,14,15,16]]
A----1,5,9,13 :
B----2,6,10,14 :
C----3,7,11,15 :
D----4,8,12,16
I want to scale the second feature B i.e,----- 2 , 6 , 10 , 14
After scaling->  B---0.0 , 0.333 , 0.667 , 1.0
I did it by extracting B feature and making a new numpy array with one feature and scaling the new array. 
How can I do it without creating any new array by just using the already defined array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use slicing and broadcasting. but you'll need to be careful regarding the shape of the slices. see the code below

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

In [3]: sc = MinMaxScaler()

In [4]: X = [ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]]

In [5]: X = np.array(X,dtype=float)

In [6]: X
Out[6]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
       [ 9., 10., 11., 12.],
       [13., 14., 15., 16.]])

In [7]: X[:,1:2] = sc.fit_transform(X[:,1:2])

In [8]: X
Out[8]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ,  3.        ,  4.        ],
       [ 5.        ,  0.33333333,  7.        ,  8.        ],
       [ 9.        ,  0.66666667, 11.        , 12.        ],
       [13.        ,  1.        , 15.        , 16.        ]])
```

slicing all the rows(:) and the columns with index 1 upto but not including 2 (1:2) we're selecting the column and preserving its shape, which is required because the minmaxscaler requires a 2D array input. and assignment by broadcasting also requires shape consistency.